# Button Router link is not working angular

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am trying to figure out how to give the `routerLink` path in button. If I give the full path, the below router code is working and I am able to see that page.

```html
[routerLink]="['/home',{outlets:{homeOutlet:':product/import/103'}}]"
```

But I have variables instead of task and id and I tried the following and not working.

```html
[routerLink]="['/home', {outlets:{homeOutlet:':(this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().productName)/import/this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().id'}}]">
```

How can I solve this issue? Please advice.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap css? If so, you can simply use `<a [routerLink]='[...]' class="btn btn-default">Text</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably work if you move it to the typescript code

```
  import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

  constructor(private router:Router){}

    public navigate() {
       string path = ':' +this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().productName +'/import/' + this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().id
       this.router.navigate(['/home', { outlets: { homeOutlet: [path] } }]);
    }
```

Then on your html file remove the attribute `[routerLink]` and just add `(click) = "navigate()"`

Comment: I tried both options, but it is not going to the homeOutlet. I tried below outside the button, its showing the value.{{this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().productName}}
{{this.productStore.activeProduct$.getValue().id}}. But inside button its not. When i inspect the code, i am seeing. ng-reflect-router-link="['/home', {outlets:{homeOutlet"